# What is the difference between "property" and "attribute"?

Tags: meaning, differences, nouns

This question has been [asked before](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28085/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property), but I am not satisfied with the answer. In the course of researching this I developed a theory and now I am unable to verify whether this might be true or against common usage because I am not a native speaker. I will just give an example because formulating it in general is more confusing than helpful.

> Jeff Atwood has the *attribute* black for the *property* hair color.

So a *property* (hair color) is a thing belonging to a class (human) while instances of a class (Jeff Atwood) have a concrete *attribute* (black) associated with this property.

Does that sound reasonable or unlikely?

Comment: The terms _attribute_ and _property_ are synonymous (check in [Collins](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/attribute) ). This means not that they are always interchangeable, but that they overlap in meaning for at least some senses. And this in turn renders the question meaningless as put. You would have to specify polysemes rather than ask 'What is the difference between [the words] “property” and “attribute”?'

Comment: Some programming languages may draw that distinction, but English does not.

Comment: As Brad says, these specific rules are rules of the 'jargon' of computer science, not English rules per se.  People are not classes, or instances of a class in English.  In writing a program you can represent people with a class, and select properties that can contain the attributes your design requires.

Comment: That might be true, that without context it is not justifiable to draw this distinction. I am not really talking about programming languages, the context is more logic, philosophy and modeling. In a similar case I found that _universe of discourse_ and _problem domain_ are often used synonymously even in specialized literature, but upon closer inspection it becomes obvious that both terms (with their original meaning) are not synonymous; just nobody cares or is aware of the difference. That is why I thought _property_ and _attribute_ may be a similar case.

Comment: I'm not personally aware of a context where property is an abstract “slot” and attribute is a concrete “value.” Some jargon does differentiate the two, but not that way. For example, Python properties are a special type of attribute that is defined procedurally.

Comment: I'll also note that programmers and (I think) mathematicians often draw this distinction between argument and parameter. But I haven't noticed it for attribute and property.

Comment: Maybe I am really biased by my programming background where you have _properties_ in classes and every instance has a (property) value for each property. Essentially I am equating (property) value with _attribute_. XML and friends are different, they call the same things _attribute_ and attribute value. Probably I am really looking for a difference where there is none because I don't like having two words for the same thing. But while looking at usage examples it seemed like this distinction is real.

Comment: Even in software design, that's improper usage.  Your comment is far closer to the mark -- "black" is Jeff's *value* of the (attribute/property) "hair color"

Answer (score -3):

EDITED

With reference to the original question, I can't see how terms specific to computer language are relevant.

There are terms used to describe aspects of general language use which go back to Aristotle's 10 categories of being, as laid out within what's now known as his 'Organon'.

The question relates to the classification of the relationship between the terms 'Jeff Attwood', 'Jeff Attwood's hair' and 'the colour of Jeff Attwood's hair'.

In terms of Aristotle's categories, 'Jeff Attwood', 'Jeff Attwood's hair', and 'the colour of Jeff Attwood's hair' would all come under 'Substance'.
I would classify 'Jeff Attwood's hirsuteness' under 'Quality', as an attribute which relates to 'Jeff Attwood'.
Furthermore, I would put 'black' under 'Quality' as an attribute which relates to 'Jeff Attwood's hair'.
In the sentence 'Jeff Attwood has black hair', in terms of the Categories, 'hair' is treated (unclearly) as an attribute of 'Jeff Attwood' and 'black' is treated as described in the previous sentence, becoming an attribute of an attribute.
For a breakdown on the categories, see the Wikipedia link previously cited or my TEDx talk on the importance of linking words to meaning through them [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYit3MYAoqM).

I trust this makes things clearer for those unfamiliar with this terminology and shows its greater relevance than computer programming terminology in this context.

ORIGINAL

From the integrated traditional liberal arts tradition within which I work, there is a link between subject and predicate in a sentence and substance and attribute with reference to [Aristotle's 10 categories of being](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categories_%28Aristotle%29#The_Praedicamenta).

The 9 attributes (excluding substance) encompass more than properties might - for instance, two of the categories relate to the substance's position with regards to space and time. Are these, strictly speaking, properties? 'Having' is one of the attributes/categories, and there is no confusion here, as there would be with 'property' used in two conflicting senses - association, or ownership.

It is a sad case of the decline in the teaching of English that this distinction has been forgotten. You can, of course, treat 'property' as synonymous with 'attribute'. The question is why. Since Aristotle's [categories are embodied](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Women-Fire-Dangerous-Things-Categories/dp/0226468046/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1391815897&sr=8-1&keywords=lakoff%20women) and express different modes of the way in which we think, I can't see how they can be separated from language.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that Aristotle didn't speak English.

Comment: @BraddSzonye - and your point is?

Comment: To state my objection less glibly: I find it strange to decry the loss of something without showing that it was ever in common use to begin with.

Comment: Also, I don't see how it answers the question. It sounds more like a response to the comments on the question.

Comment: @BraddSzonye - Firstly, if you read my answer attentively, you'll see I made the point (referenced) which states that the categories are embodied. They are part of how we think, in whatever language we use. I think that shows quite clearly they've never been out of use. For just one example that goes back to using the attributes as a compositional tool in Latin c 1175 see Copeland and Sluiter (2009), pp 34 and p 192 for the influence of this approach on Chaucer. I rest my case.

Comment: @BraddSzonye - Let me try again: Whenever we form a concept, we use the categories. Whenever we express our thoughts in grammatical form, we draw on at least two of the categories. Sister Miriam Joseph's book 'The Trivium' covers the whole subject in more detail should you wish to understand where I'm coming from, or go back to Aristotle's Organon.

Comment: On further thought, I see now the point you're trying to make. But it sounds more like you're positing your opinion on what words should mean, rather than describing how they are actually used.

Comment: @BraddSzonye - Thanks - I think paragraph 2 spells it out clearly enough. If you want to rewrite, fine, go ahead. Happy to discuss further once you've taken a look at the sources I've referenced. I've nothing to add at this point.

Comment: A particular philosophy, like a programming language can use words as they please. This is just another jargon and does not change what the actual words mean until and unless the new meaning is accepted in general.

Comment: @Oldcat - As the mental distinctions to which the words Aristotle used to distinguish his Categories have been around ever since people started to create symbols, and his terms have been widely accepted and commented on over the last 2,000 years, far from any 'new' meaning being implied, I am simply reiterating an existing meaning, in existing words, which have been widely accepted. See the links to Wikipedia and my TEDx talk above.