# Is the name of a person an attribute or a property?

Tags: word-choice

People have names. Well, they don't have to but giving names to people, or people giving names to themselves, makes it much easier to reference them in speech and writing. Are names attributes or are they properties of people?

**Update**
Not relevant to the question itself but maybe interesting to know: The reason why I asked that question is because English is not my mother's tongue and in my native language, attribute and property are pretty much interchangeable by definition as attribute is a foreign word, imported from French, and translates to property. Yet in daily use people seem to make a slight distinction between those two terms. There are situations where using one of them seems natural while using the other one seems "strange", albeit not incorrect.

When reading English texts, I quite often read about "attributes of a person" where I would have expected the term "properties". So I was wondering if there is also a distinction in daily use. Answers to similar questions here sometimes hint towards such a distinction but they always refer to both words in terms of "computer language" and computer language is not necessarily bound to natural use of these words. So I was wondering, how would a native speaker refer to the name of a person? Would they say it is an attribute of that person or what they say it is a property of that person and why would they favor one over the other one?

Comment: Relevant (at least in understanding the question) but not identical: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28085/what-is-the-difference-between-attribute-and-property/28098

Comment: @StuartF The other question refers to these words in terms of "computer language" where correct usage of these words is often just a matter of definition (one could have defined that HTML tags have properties instead of having attributes). And these definitions are often inconsistent and choice frequently seems random to me.

Comment: Some of the answers to the question I posted go into the issue more generally. The distinction between a property and an attribute isn't a widely used one (at least in English; even in computer science I'm not sure how common it is), and it's impossible to answer the question without knowing the difference between an attribute and a property. If you have alternative definitions of attribute and property, you should post them.

Comment: It seems to me that "a property" attaches to an inanimate object - usually an uncountable noun: "One property of iron is that it is magnetic.", and "attribute" to a sentient creature "The dog had all the attributes that were required to be the perfect companion." Attributes tend to be subjective, whereas properties tend to be objective. A name is objective - it is thus a property.

Comment: How are you trying to distinguish the terms?

Comment: I looked in a dictionary.  "**Property:**  An attribute, quality, or characteristic."   I think we often use *attribute, property, characteristic* interchangeably.

Comment: Can you say something more about what you consider the actual the difference between 'attribute' and 'property'? The are also vaguely the same in English, but also have vague differences that a dictionary definition doesn't make clear.

Comment: @Mitch I don't consider them to be different but if they were totally interchangeable, then people wold use them at random. What word would you use to refer to the name of a person? Either one at random? No? Then apparently these words seem to make a difference to you. Please post an answer, tell me the word and explain why this word and not the other one.

Comment: @Mecki I'm sure the philosophers (or mathematicians) have dealt with this kind of thing. A person's name I would call an attribute, but not a property - I think that means a property somehow more necessary in definition? Like maybe -all- people have a property, but individuals have attributes? Mathematical logicians may (or may not) distinguish them and then need proofs to show that a property of an entity shows set inclusion (a member of the set of all entities with that property).

Comment: But there's a difference between mathematical properties and/or attributes and how non-mathematicians use those two words. What is the difference between the two words in your native, non-mathematical) language? For such borrowings it could well be the same as in English. Things are not clear enough for me to give an official ELU answer.

Comment: If things don't work out here, you may want to try it out on [philosophy.se].

Comment: Aristotle distinguishes between _properties_ and _accidents_. The former are intrinsic to the nature of something, while the latter are arbitrary. Of course, Aristotle didn't have a good handle on what was actually intrinsic; he thought the brain existed to cool the blood.

Comment: In another discussion someone claimed a property is something someone has (e.g. a body weight, an age) and an attribute is rather a something that has been "attributed" to that person (the person is beautiful or intelligent). Yet I could not find any objective source that would backup this claim.